# How to combine the honourific conjugation and て form?

Tags: verbs, て-form, keigo

I was trying to use combined verbs like 忘れてしまう, 連れて行く or 持ってくる with the honourific conjugation お stem になる. What is the correct way to use that conjugation with these types of verbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ～てしまう, you turn the subsidiary verb into the お + 連用形 + になる form, as in:

> 忘れてしまう → 忘れて**お**しまい**になる** <sub>(You can also say 忘れてしまわれる)</sub>

... or, as @naruto pointed out, turn the main verb into the お + 連用形 + になる form, as in:

> **お**忘れ**になっ**てしまう

---

For ～ていく, you turn the subsidiary verb いく(行く) into おいでになる or お + 連用形 + になる, as in:

> 連れていく → 連れて**お**いで**になる** or 連れて**お**いき**になる** <sub>(You can also say 連れていらっしゃる, 連れていかれる)</sub>

---

For ～てくる, you turn the subsidiary verb くる(来る) into おいでになる.　(～て**お**き**になる**　sounds incorrect.)

> 持ってくる → 持っ**て**おいで**になる** <sub>(You can also say 持っていらっしゃる, 持ってこられる)</sub>

Comment: 「お忘れになってしまう」もアリかも

Comment: @naruto おお・・・確かに・・・

Comment: @Chocolate thanks so much! Really useful breakdown ^-^